# Angular Application on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular, angular6

I want to use wordpress for only landing page . My core frontend application is on angular.

Is it a good idea to use wordpress for only landing page and after clicking login button redirect it to my angular application ? What do you think about advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good reasons for wanting to do this. WordPress has a large community of addons which can add lots of features to even the simplest landing page.

Outside of this, content management alone can make WordPress worth it. A few simple text changes and recompilations later and you may be wishing the Angular App was backed by a CMS as capable as WordPress.

That said I am working on a plugin which brings advanced Angular capabilities to WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Using Xo for Angular you can inject code from other plugins which attach to wp_head and wp_footer into your index dynamically. Additionally data for items like posts, pages, menus, and options can be retrieved using the Xo API.

You could create a page which has custom options in WordPress and retrieve that content using the Xo API. For example if you had a header image you may make this selectable in the WordPress admin and get that image info to display in your Angular component.

Documentation (work in progress): https://angularxo.io/

Plugin github: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core

Example theme: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

Let me know what you think, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cant see much point in using a whole CMS just for a login page.. if you are wanting to use WordPress to manage content etc as well as your login page.. and have angular powering the front-end have a look at headless WordPress.. good starting point can be found here:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/off-with-their-heads-building-a-headless-wordpress-to-manage-content-bb04e6b2a792

If you want a simple login authentication before you access your angular app you can do it in so many ways.. php, node etc..